# Type checking with omit params

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to define some type based on a base Type.

- 'Simple' Type has a name and type property
- 'Base' Type has a property name that cannot be 'text' or 'radio'
- I create a 'Radio' and a 'Texto' type

But when I create an object with type: 'radio', it does not make mandatory the 'radio' or 'freq' properties...

I don't know why...

Can someone can highlight the issue please ?

```
type Simple = {
    name: string
    type: string
}

type Base = Exclude<Simple, {type: 'text'|'radio'}>

type Radio = Base & {
    type: 'radio',
    radio: string,
    freq: string
};

type Texto = Base & {
    type: 'text'
    label: string
}

type Field = Radio | Texto | Base

/**
 * I expect to see an error thrown with 'freq' and 'radio' is missing here...
 */
const myRadio:Field = {
    type: 'radio',
    name:'snig'
}
```

Comment: *'Base' Type has a property name that cannot be 'text' or 'radio'* - `Exclude` leaves `Simple` unchanged since `Simple` does not have `type` field working as discriminant. I don't think discriminating unions in typescript support things like "name that cannot be something".

Comment: TypeScript lacks *negated types* so there's no specific type of the form `string & not ("text" | "radio")`.  `Exclude` filters unions, and `Simple` is not a union, and neither is `string`.  There was a PR for negated types at [ms/TS#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) but it was never merged. For now you'd need to use a generic type instead to get behavior like this, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WP8VJW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your comments, highlights. I'm a bit disappointed but I need to accept reality. I'll accept this answer as soon as it'll be wrotten.

Comment: I will write an answer when I get a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific type in TypeScript that corresponds to all `string` values except `"text"` and `"radio"`, so you can't give `Base` a specific type that distinguishes it from `Texto` or `Radio`.  That would require so-called *negated types* as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) but never released.  So you can't say `string & not ("text" | "radio")`.  [The `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) can only filter [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) but since neither `string` nor `Simple` are union types, it has no effect.

---

In the absence of specific types that work the way you want, you could try a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type and use it to *constrain* the input values.  So instead of `const myRadio: Field = {⋯}`, you'd need to write something like `const myRadio: Field<"radio"> = {⋯}`.  Or, if you don't want to manually write that type argument, you could write a utility function to *infer* the type argument, and instead write `const myRadio= field({⋯})` and `myRadio` will have its type inferred as `Field<"radio">`.  It could look like this:

```
type KnownField = Radio | Texto;

type Field<T extends string> =
    T extends KnownField['type'] ?
    Extract<KnownField, { type: T }> :
    Simple;

const field = <T extends (string & {}) | KnownField['type']>(
    t: { type: T } & Field<T>
): Field<T> => t;
```

Here `Field<T>` is implemented as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that discriminates `KnownField` using `T` as a discriminant if it applies (using [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union), or else falling back to `Simple`.  And `field()` is a helper function that gives you the inference you want.

Let's try it:

```
const myRadio = field({
    type: 'radio',
    name: 'snig'
}); // error!
//   Type '{ type: "radio"; name: string; }' is missing the following properties from type
//  '{ type: "radio"; radio: string; freq: string; }': radio, freq
```

That's the error you wanted.  And if you inspect `myRadio`, its type is `Radio`.  The following code compiles with no errors:

```
const t = field({ type: "text", name: "abc", label: "abc" });
// const t: Texto
const r = field({ type: "radio", name: "abc", radio: "abc", freq: "abc" });
// const r: Radio
const s = field({ type: "random", name: "abc" });
// const s: Simple
```

Looks good.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgWzAG2gXigbwFBT1AOwEMEIAuKAZ2ACc4CBzXfUSC6ux7AX2z9egAlIgBM4AeygZ4SVFABkWZngEUA5DVES1AGmVRNY8e1r0Ge-FABmNCAEcTnJtwDc-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)